# Cursorfetch: The number of variables declared in the INTO list must match that of selected columns. in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server

I don't understand what is the error. I tried everything. I created a new table All are ok I get value in select statement but still this problem come

```
insert into tTransaction (TransactionType,
TransactionSubType,
ReferenceID,
ProductID,
FromLocationID,
CreatedBy,
CreationDate,
TransactionDate,
TransactionQty
)
select TransType,TranSubType,RefID,ProdID,LocID,
       CreatedBy,CreationDate,TransDate,TransQty
from Shiping_TempData
```

Comment: The query you posted has a syntax error; there is an extraneous comma after TransactionQty.

Comment: I removed that Comma but still the same error come

Comment: Is there any kind of trigger defined on the `tTransaction` table?

Comment: This is not problem.the problem is near fetch next from [cursor_name] into ...